# When not to use OpenId connect

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, oauth, openid, openid-connect

We are building a web application that also includes webAPI's. These WebAPIs needs to be exposed to other applications as well (other internal application on different subDomain or 3rd party application). We are thinking of using OpenId Connect, so that not only we will be able to give access_token but also id_token for authentication.

Now the question is 'Should my main application also use openId connect' for authentication/authorization. I am not in favor of this. As per my understanding, only external applications should use openid connect to use main application's resources. And internal applications (main as well as application on different sub-domain) can work with regular cookie based authentication.

For instance, main application is MyWebApp.com (this includes webapi as well). Other internal applications are maps.MyWebApp.com, admin.MyWebApp.com, payroll.MyWebApp.com.

Other 3rd party application could be OtherWebApp.com.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Should my main application also use openid connect?" 
Advantages 
   - paves the way for single sign on
   - modularizes your authentication so you're not implementing different authentication solutions.
   - you have the option of using the same Web api from your main app. (although you could just use the oauth2 client credentials flow and simply skip the openid connect authentication part) 
Disadvantages 
   - if you only had one client app then this could be overkill
   - you're adding complexity to the app by making it depend on an authentication server app (but modularizing has advantages too)

I don't know your scenario completely but I'm inclined to say yes. Although, I'd definitely turn off the consent screen from oauth2 for your trusted main app. If you don't use openid connect for authentication, it shouldn't be too hard to convert your main app to use it later

Comment: Hi sdoxsee, My application is a SPA (with multiple modules). Each module's landing page is served by asp.net MVC. In short, it is a mixture of webapi and server side page. Which approach can protect webapi and cshtml view?